# Node.js: Running example of Chat?

Tags: windows, apache, node.js

Trying to setup an example for node.js chat on Windows x64.

Command line:

```
D:\Websites\dev\chat>node server.js
Server at http://127.0.0.1:8001/
```

Now when server part runs, trying `http://dev/chat/index.html`

After submitting Name, it gives me "error connecting to server".

Same error message on http://chat.nodejs.org/

Does the thing actually work? =)

Do I need to set up an Apache's mod_proxy to handle /join to port 8001?

Comment: Got sources from http://github.com/ry/node_chat/tree/master

Comment: did u try connecting to http://127.0.0.1:8001 ?

Comment: @vinayr: yep, nothing there, connection is getting reset in the browser and using telnet.

Comment: The local copy from https://github.com/ry/node_chat works fine for me. I get the same error as you on http://chat.nodejs.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of the issues are with using `http://dev/chat/index.html` and also, I suspect, with:

> Do I need to set up an Apache's mod_proxy to handle /join to port 8001?

Node's [`http` module](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html) is more for creating the server than it is for integrating with other servers like Apache. (It's possible, e.g. [iisnode](https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode), but not the default.)

While `node server.js` is running, you should be able to access `index.html` via either:

```
http://localhost:8001/
http://127.0.0.1:8001/
```

Then, `/join`, `/recv`, `/send`, etc. should be able to route through the same origin.

Otherwise, using `http://dev/` has 2 problems:

1. Requests will route based on the current address. For example, [`/join`](https://github.com/ry/node_chat/blob/master/client.js#L470) will request `http://dev/join` rather than `http://127.0.0.1:8001/join`, likely resulting in a `404` response. And, even if you modified the client script to specify the origin...
2. [Same-origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). Pages requested from `http://dev/` cannot make Ajax requests to `http://127.0.0.1:8001` [without exceptions](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/), which this demo does not have established.

Comment: The issue was solved by specifying different port (18001). However there was nothing using 8001 before.